# How can I implement this HTML side date pipe as TypeScript code in order to convert a TimeStamp into a formatted Date?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-pipe

into an Angular application I am converting a variable containing a date value in timestamp format, something like this:

```
patientBirthDate:  
t {seconds: 450568800, nanoseconds: 0}
nanoseconds: 0
seconds: 450568800
__proto__:
```

into a date from the HTML of a component, in this way:

```
<span class="image-text">{{patient.birthDate.toMillis() | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</span>
```

and it works fine. Now I have to implement the same exact behavior (starting from the same field) from TypeScript code. I was trying to do:

```
console.log("patientBirthDate: ", patient.birthDate.toMillis());
```

but then what can I do to convert it into a formatted date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject `DatePipe` into your component's constructor and use `this.datePipe.transform(date, '<format>');`

```js
class Component {
  constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

  formatPatientBirthDate(patient: Patient): string {
    return this.datePipe.transform(patient.birthDate.toMillis(), 'dd/MM/yyyy');
  }
}
```